# can someone explain me this django views part

Tags: python, django

def download(request , path):

```
file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT , path)
if os.path.exists(file_path):
    with open(file_path , 'rb') as file:
        response = hr(file.read(),content_type="application/admin_upload")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline;filename='+os.path.basename(file_path)
        return response

raise Http404
```

---

i saw one on how to upload a img by the admin and the code works fine but i dont understand this part :/

Comment: The question is: What is `hr`? The other parts should be clear.

Comment: explain this one : (file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT , path)
if os.path.exists(file_path):
    with open(file_path , 'rb') as file:
        response = hr(file.read(),content_type="application/admin_upload")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline;filename='+os.path.basename(file_path)
        return response
raise Http404 )

Comment: In my opinion the documentation of [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) is pretty clear. What questions do you have about this function?

Comment: response = hr(file.read(),content_type="application/admin_upload")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline;filename='+os.path.basename(file_path)
         i understand its sending httpresponse but not the others